# Origin of "abort" in cryptography proofs

Tags: terminology, game, proof

It's a very standard move in a game-based security proof to have a transition in which we "abort" on some event such as a hash collision; the two games are identical apart from the abort step, and we add the probability of the abort to the advantage term at the end. Example: https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1368

I'm curious if anyone has explicitly formalized and justified this step. The way aborts are used seems very similar to but slightly different from either the "failure events" in [Shoup's paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/332) or the "bad events" in [Bellare and Rogaway](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/331); neither of those papers contains the word "abort". In particular, it's clear that in the case of "failure events"/"bad events" that the attacker keeps making queries and still returns a final result, while it's not clear to me what happens after an "abort".

Note that this is not related to aborts *in the protocol*, as in eg Dilithium signing or Kyber encapsulation rejection; this is to do with aborts used as a tool in proofs about a protocol.

Comment: Aborts are just a simple special case of bad events, where you have two equivalent-until-bad games but one aborts immediately when `bad` is set to true.

Comment: What does the attacker get when one aborts?

Comment: OK, that is a fair question. There are probably many reasonable variants, and not all may be equivalent. Aborts are clearly a special case of bad events if "abort" means to raise an exception that the attacker can catch (and the game's oracles give empty responses to all subsequent queries). You could implement an exception by a special `abort' return value from the game's oracles.

Comment: If "abort" means that this execution somehow "doesn't count" towards the attacker's advantage, then I'm not sure if it's equivalent. I recall [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/418.pdf) studying similar issues in the context of CCA security definitions. Do we quantify over attackers that don't trigger the abort? Do we punish the attacker if an abort happened? The answers to these questions actually do actually matter to the definition. If these (long) comments address your question, I can promote them to true responses.

Comment: Mainly I'm curious to know if there's an answer already in the literature, whether this was answered when aborts were introduced, or whether there's a discussion of it since trying to formalize the idea. If I were to try to formalize it myself, I'd start with something like your "special exception, no subsequent responses" proposal.

Comment: The way I understand aborts in proof is: a way of explicitly describing what the reduction to a specific scheme does (the reduction being from the main game or some intermediary hop). So it's similar to the bad event concept. But if we have the reduction working as a "simulator" for the game, the abort event explicitly represents the moment where the reduction wins its own game. As for the return value, in my readings I haven't seen any consistent approach and in most cases the return values are not specified.

Comment: But I think it doesn't matter so much as long as it's consistent and allows arguing the reduction soundly. In particular, for the games $G_i$ and $G_j$ (played by $\mathcal A$) that are equivalent until some abort; then the reduction $\mathcal B$ will simulate $G_j$ until abort. Now $\mathcal A$ advantage difference between both games is upper bounded by the advantage of the reduction. This is my understanding of how aborts are used in game hops.

Comment: The earliest instances of this terminology I could find were [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_7) and [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/192). The latter specifies what happens on abort in page 6.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting. The use of "abort" must be early. For example, Goldreich used it in his textbook, and we can find it in his draft from July 2000 (see p421, "in this case A' aborts"):

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/PSBookFrag/sign1.ps

This example is in the proof of Lamport's one-time signature (1979), and it is used in the case when the reduction can not succeed. One may exhaustively search the related literature for earlier use of "abort" in this line.

This example may also show a difference between "abort" and "bad event": if the reduction algorithm knows it fails already, it simply aborts; otherwise, a bad event happened but the reduction does not know and continues.